# How to instantiate a templated class with non-default constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor, variadic-templates

Please consider the following example:

```
class Generator {
public:
    Generator(int n)
        : m_n(n)
    {
    }

    int f()
    {
        return m_n;
    }
private: 
    int m_n;
};

template<class BaseClass>
class Transformer : public BaseClass
{
public:
    Transformer(int mult, int add)
        : m_mult(mult)
        , m_add(add)
    {

    }

    int f()
    {
        return BaseClass::f() * m_mult + m_add;
    }

private:
    int m_add;
    int m_mult;
};
```

Imaging there are more `Generator` classes, which have different arguments in their constructors. Now I want to instantiate a class consisting of both passing all the required parameters.
So I tried the following, but `Generator` is apparently not recognized as a base class:

```
class TG : public Transformer<Generator>
{
public:
    TG(int n, int mult, int add)
        : Generator(n)              // error C2614: 'TG': illegal member initialization: 'Generator' is not a base or member
        , Transformer(mult, add)
    {}
};

TG t(n,mult,add);
```

Next I tried template specialization:

```
template<> Transformer<Generator>::Transformer(int n, int mult, int add)    // error C2244: 'Transformer<Generator>::Transformer': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
    : Transformer(mult,add)
    , Generator(n)
{};

Transformer<Generator> t(n,mult,add);
```

How can I instantiate a template, which has non-default constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Imaging there are more Generator classes, which have different arguments in their constructors. Now I want to instantiate a class consisting of both passing all the required parameters

It seems to me that, if you can use at least C++11, what do you need is a variadic template constructor written as follows

```
template <typename ... As>
Transformer (int mult, int add, As && ... as)
    : BaseClass{std::forward<As>(as)...}, m_mult{mult}, m_add{add}
 { }
```

The idea is that the constructor receive first the values for the members (`m_mult` and `m_add`) that are ever required, next a variadic list of arguments for the base class (with perfect forwarding; not necessary but can be useful, generally speaking). It's necessary this order because a variadic list of deduces argument must be in last position.

The `TG` constructor become

```
template <typename ... As>
TG (int mult, int add, As && ... as)
   : Transformer{mult, add, std::forward<As>(as)...}
 { }
```

Comment: Sorry, that may have been mislieading. I have rephrased the question. However, what do you do, if you have more generator classes which have different arguments in their constructor?

Comment: @MiB_Coder - I see... yes, it's a totally different problem; give me some minutes and I rewrite my answer proposing a solution

Comment: @MiB_Coder - Answer modified. A doubt: you tagged only C++; is OK a C++11 solution for you?